# nodejs routing: all routes with authentication except first page

Tags: node.js, routes

I am using passport for login.
I want to have all routes except `'/'` to require login.

I have a

```
ensureAuthenticated
```

function, which checks I am authenticated.

I'd rather not like to have to put into every route the middleware call:

```
app.get('/first', ensureAuthenticated,...)
app.get('/second', ensureAuthenticated,...)
```

Is there a way to assign `ensureAuthenticated` to all routes except `'/'`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`app.all`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.all) for that:

```
// regular route
app.get('/', ...);

// make sure all following routes will be passed through ensureAuthenticated
app.all('*', ensureAuthenticated);
app.get('/first',  ...);
app.get('/second', ...);
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks for this elegant solution. Note: of course I have a app.post('/login') route also - this needs to go BEFORE app.all as well in order for my login to work :)